# Asp.net MVC 2 relation without Foreign Key with Entity Framework 4 Or With Foreign Key

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

1 - Is it necessary to have foreign key to obtain a Relation in Entity Framework between each entity.? 
2 - I have a Language Table and many many table with a foreign key related to the language table. Is it right to add this foreign key or I should do something else ?  
Ex: 
**Language** 
LangID 
LangName

**TableTextA** 
TblAID 
TextInfo 
LangID

**TableTextB** 
TblBID 
TextInfo 
LangID

**TableTextC** 
TblCID 
TextInfo 
LangID 
etc ...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always get the Language info by using the `Linq` queries like:

```
YourContainer db = new YourContainer();

var Text = from m in db.TableTextASet
           join n in db.LanguageSet on n.LangID equals m.LangID
           select new
           {
               Id = m.TblAID,
               Text = m.TextInfo,
               Language = n.LangName
           };
```

So setting the association is not really necessary. However I strongly recommend you to do so.